# SignalR callback in javascript

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

Is there a way to pass a callback function for SignalR? Right now I have on my `site.js`

```
messageHub.client.sendProgress = function (progress) {
        //doSomething with progress
}
```

What I would like to have is

```
messageHub.client.sendProgress = function (progress,callback) {
        callback(progress);
}
```

This would enable me to define different callback functions from web pages for the same signalR method.
Right now I am doing it in kind of a hack-ish way by defining a function on my web page

```
function fnSendProgress(progress) //define this for site.js.
    {
        //do something here
    }
```

and then in `site.js` calling it by

```
messageHub.client.sendProgress = function (progress) {
        debugger;
        //have a definition of a function called fnSendProgress(progress)
        //if found it will call it else call default
        if (typeof fnSendProgress == 'function') {
            fnSendProgress(progress);
        }
        else {
                //do something at site.js level
        }

    };
```

It works, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner method.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: From where do you want to specify the callback function? Do you want the server to provide the callback function when you invoke the client-side hub method? Your question isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use closures:

```
function createfunction(callback)
{
    return function(progress) { callback(progress); }
}


messageHub.client.sendProgress = createFunction(callback)
```

First you define a function "createFunction", which given a callback returns another function with one argument, which calls the specified callback.

Then you assign the result of calling that function to signalr's sendProgress.

In other words: for each callback you want you dynamically generate a function with one argument, which calls the callback and passes the argument to it.